# How to add My Compare List link to Top Links?

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm trying to add *My Compare List* link to top links near the My Wishlist.
Where is its' template?
I looked lots of files but i couldnt find it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking in layout XML. There are a couple of blocks (and templates) involved in that area of the display.

From *`./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`*:

```
<default>
    <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
        <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
        <!-- snip... -->
    </block>
</default>
```

This is where the "space" for these links is created. Other modules use this space as necessary to add links or blocks which contain links. For example, from *`./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml`*...

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

...and from *`./app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/wishlist.xml`*...

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
        <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
    </reference>
    <!-- snip... -->
</default>
```

You will probably want to create a link for viewing compare following the example of the customer module:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog">
            <label>Compare Products</label>
            <url helper="catalog/product_compare/getListUrl"/> <!-- @see Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare::getListUrl() */
            <title>Compare Products</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>10</position> <!-- adjust as needed -->
            <liParams/>
            <!--
                if you want to use the standard behavior, you will need a custom
                helper which returns the popwin() js string and feeds it to the
                "onclick" node below:
            <aParams>
                <onclick helper="your_module/getPopwinStuff"/>
            </aParams>
            -->
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Keep in mind that this is normally viewed in a popup and so may require additional styling to have the look and feel you want.